# How to organize a larger PHP project

Tags: php, project-organization

I'm trying to organize a larger PHP project with more than 50 files in code, not counting the resource files.

It looks like this:

- administrator files (php code and resource files)
- database framework
- resource files (images, templates, including PHP templates, CSS)
- CSS files
- scripts (Javascript and jQuery)
- PHP code (classes, controls)
- PHP and HTML scripts (acting as pages, placed in root)

How does one, properly organize a larger PHP project like this one?

Comment: This question is off-topic, localized, and also subjective. None of which follows the Stack Overflow guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a project that holds 50 files is not even called a project, in the real concept of the word.

Take a look at how the most used frameworks do that and you will get a place to start.

Some PHP frameworks:

- [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/)
- [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/)
- [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)

So you can have a good reference, there is a simple good practice on PHP projects that tells that only the template, stylesheet and scripts files should be in a public directory, such as /var/www on your host. All the core application should be on a higher-level structure, for example:

```
src/ (The core application)
public/ (The public directory)
    css/
    img/
    js/
    index.php
```

You can, then, have a .htaccess file on the public directory as well, so you can control the requests.

But again, project architecture and structure organization goes a lot further than those simple tips.

Comment: Wait... 50 files is not a project? And why not?

Comment: Well, when we talk about agile project management, a project is something that demans more than 1000 hours of work from a specific team. Yes, the 50 file project is a project, but not a real project in the world of project management. I think you understand what I'm trying to say...

Comment: Not really. You're saying that if you have an *"individual or collaborative enterprise planned and designed to achieve an aim"* (http://google.com/search?q=define:project) but no project management, then it's not a project?

Comment: The rest of your answer is good enough though, even though this question is off-topic, too localized and debatable.

Comment: First of all the project is not complete yet, and it needs reorganization. Second, you talked about the application itself being on a higher-level structure, could you elaborate as to how one would do that, or point me to the right direction. I know that you mean that the application should be outside, but how would the specific functions in the required script files be called in the public domain of the application.

Comment: That's where you usually look for frameworks. They do exactly that, focusing on the core concepts of the application - routing, secutiry. session management, etc. You would only need to implement your features of your specific application. It's really hard to tell you how to do it since I don't know your structure or your application concepts. But I think that the right direction would be start looking for a PHP Framework that suits your application better.

Comment: As a novice I'm looking for proper organisation and structure of my files and directories, and I.k. it mostly depend of type and size of app. But there must be some standards about organisation and naming directories, scripts etc... and I don't realy find helpful sentence "Hey look at some popular framework." because I code in core PHP , or "If it has less than 50 files it could not been called project" I don't agree with this, projects can be smaller and bigger, but people love to name it a project. I'm looking for best way how to protect my files which don't have sessions?

Comment: "total files" and even "total lines" in no way determines the business size. You could have a very very simple app that provides only one feature and so 3 web pages in 3 files and a handful of PHP/JS/React to do things. I think you'd be better avoiding ambiguous statements and instead perhaps stating something related to the necessity or usefulness of strict organisation with very few files/scripts

Answer (score 2):

As it was already pointed out: you should separate the publicly available files ( css, images, flash, fonts and application entry points ) in one directory , and the rest of application - in another.

I think more important is the structure with the application itself.

- main framework, architectural class
- components and 3rd party libs
- custom code

  - shared code

    - application logic
    - persistence
    - templates
  - admin module
  - public module

But this will depend on your personal preferences.